# CentOS 6 or Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, mysql

I need MySQL (with a lot of querys) and an HTTPs service.

Should I use CentOS 6 or Ubuntu 12.04 on a virtual server?

Are there differences in the performance (with default config) or differences in security (for resellers)?

Thanks very much for a short comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably both get your job done, my opinion is choose the flavor that you are most comfortable with. The ubuntu uses .deb packages and the CentOS the .rpm

Theoretically the CentOS is more stable and better hardware support but Ubuntu is more user friendly.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu Server 12.04 ships with a 3.5.0 kernel.
Centos 6.5 ships with a 2.6.32 kernel.
In CentOS, most of the system software is "stable", while in Ubuntu the software is "recent".
If your virtualization system supports 3.5.0 kernel and you are more familiar with new versions of software, choose Ubuntu.
If you prefer a more stable server, choose CentOS, because it's a repackaged Redhat.